# Perform a particular ILIKE query on Postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a problem with a query in Postgres.

I have a column with values such as:

```
id@@@Name1@@@other text@@@other_text@@@other_text@@@CODE@@@other_text###    
id@@@Name2@@@other text@@@other_text@@@other_text@@@CODE@@@other_text###   
id@@@Name3@@@other text@@@other_text@@@other_text@@@CODE@@@other_text###
```

Each row can have different string  suchs as the above.
The `@@@` separates each part of the string-block.

The `###` separates each string-block.

`@@@` and `###` are so a  "references".

With my query I have to find, in example:

- The row which block has  `Name1` and `CODE='X-X'`

The query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column ILIKE '%**Name1**@@@%@@@%@@@**X-X**%'
```

doesn't work.
It doesn't work because  the `%` makes the query  take ALL possible parts of text between.

So potentially, it can take (mistakenly) also the table row with Name1 (ok), but where the code X-X is, instead, of the string-block of the Name10 as the example below:

1@@@**Name1**@@@othertext@@@othertext@@@WRONGCODE@@@othertext### ...
... 10@@@Name10@@@othertext@@@othertext@@@**X-X**@@@othertext###

---

SQL provides only 2 wild cards:

- `%` = take all ,
- `_` = jolly only 1 char

But I don't know how much characters are in the *othertext* part of the block...

Is there any possible way to perform this with regex? Or make the `%` work only between 2 fixed parts?

Comment: The first thing to do (and this is an emergency) is to fire whoever came with this evil way of storing data. The next thing to do is to type "@@@" and "###" in the various text fields in the app and check if it crashes. Then change the schema to something sane that a database can use to make your searches fast.

Comment: You're right :) . Thank you.

Comment: PS: Fortunately each column has max of 5 string block, not more...

Comment: Note if you want to polish the turd a little bit you could do two rounds of split_part() to turn this string into a 2D array and store that instead of the string. It would be a little bit faster to search...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `split_part()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE split_part(column, '@@@', 2) ILIKE 'Name1' 
  and split_part(column, '@@@', 6) = 'X-X'
```

`split_part()` splits the input string based on the delimiter (second parameter) into individual elements. The third parameter identifies the number of the elements (starting at 1, which would be the `id` in your case)

---

As this gets quite cumbersome if you need to use that as part of other statements, I would create a view, that turns the blocks into columns that are arrays:

```
create view blocks_and_elements 
as
select ... other columns from the table ...,
       string_to_array(blocks[1], '@@@') as block_1,
       string_to_array(blocks[2], '@@@') as block_2,
       string_to_array(blocks[3], '@@@') as block_3
from (       
  select ... other columns from the table ...,
         string_to_array(data, '###') as blocks
  from the_table
) t1
```

This is a bit faster than calling `split_part` multiple times as the parsing/splitting is only done twice per row, not twice for each item.

Then you can do something like:

```
select *
from blocks_and_elements
where block_1[2] = 'Name1'
  and block_1[6] = 'X-X'
```

Or if you need to check multiple items:

```
select *
from blocks_and_elements
where 'Name1' in (block_1[2], block_2[2])
  and block_1[6] = 'X-X'
```

---

Another option is to create one array with all elements from the same position:

```
create view elements
as
select pk, 
       array[block_1[2], block_2[2], block_3[2]] as names,
       array[block_1[6], block_2[6], block_3[6]] as codes
from (       
  select pk, 
         string_to_array(blocks[1], '@@@') as block_1,
         string_to_array(blocks[2], '@@@') as block_2,
         string_to_array(blocks[3], '@@@') as block_3
  from (       
    select pk, 
           string_to_array(data, '###') as blocks
    from the_table
  ) t1 
) t1
```

Then you can do queries like:

```
select *
from elements
where 'Name1'= any(names)
  and 'X-X' = any(codes);
```

---

And there is also the option to convert the whole delimited string into a JSON value so that you can access the elements by key, rater than position.

Comment: Thansk you, shouldn't I've before to split each single block with ###   ?

Comment: the `###` doesn't seem relevant as it comes _after_ those values.

Comment: update, this work only if the searched things are in the first block.

In example this solution don't work if I search on name2 - code2 , cause this match only the name1-code1

Comment: @Th3Gh0st: then you'll need another level of `split_part()` for the `###` elements

Comment: Yeah ;) Thanks again

Comment: @Th3Gh0st: see my edit for a more efficient solution using `string_to_array()`

Comment: Nice improvement! Thank you for your time!